# Automatically scroll to selected row in datatable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I am building a Shiny app where I render a Leaflet map of the `nc` counties from the `sf`
package alongside a datatable that contains all the info of the counties. I have 'linked' the layer of the counties in the map with the datatable so that a county can be selected either by clicking on it on the map or in the datatable.

Here is the code of my app:

```
# Load packages ----
library(shiny)
library(sf)
library(hash)

# User interface ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=4,
      style = "height: 96vh; overflow-y: auto",
      p("in my actual app there are a bunch of buttons and selection inputs here that are used to generate the spatial dataframe object shown in the map")
    ),
    mainPanel(width=8,
      tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(47vh) !important;}"),
      leafletOutput("map"),
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")  
    )
  )
)

# Server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
    st_transform(crs=4326)
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(-79, 35, 7) %>% 
      addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
      addPolygons(data = nc, 
                  color="#000000",
                  layerId = ~CNTY_ID,
                  group="Counties",
                  highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", 
                                                      weight = 2,
                                                      opacity=0.7,
                                                      bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
      addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap"),
        overlayGroups = c("Counties"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
      )
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(nc,
                                                     selection= "single",
                                                     options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                                                                    scrollY = "47vh",
                                                                    dom = 't',
                                                                    paging = FALSE))})
  
  id_dict <- hash()
  for (i in 1:nrow(nc)) {
    id_dict[[as.character(nc[i,]$CNTY_ID)]] <- i
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
    clicked_county <- input$map_shape_click$id
    clicked_id <- id_dict[[as.character(clicked_county)]]
    change_selection(clicked_id, clicked_county, from_table = FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
    clicked_id <- input$table_rows_selected
    clicked_county <- nc[input$table_rows_selected,]$CNTY_ID
    print(clicked_id)
    change_selection(clicked_id, clicked_county, from_table = TRUE)
  })
  
  change_selection <- function(clicked_id, clicked_county, from_table){
    if(!from_table) {
      dataTableProxy("table") %>%
        selectRows(NULL) %>%
        selectRows(which(input$table_rows_all == clicked_id))
        # SOME CODE HERE TO SCROLL TO THE SELECTED ROWS
    } else if (from_table) {  
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        removeShape("highlighted_county") %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc[nc$CNTY_ID==clicked_county,],
                    layerId = "highlighted_county",
                    weight=6,
                    opacity = 1,
                    color="white"
        )
    }
  }
  
  

}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When selecting a county by clicking it in the `table`, the corresponding polygon on the `map` is highlighted. When selecting a county on the `map`, the corresponding row in `table` is selected, *however* I would like `table` to automatically scroll to this corresponding row as well so that it automatically comes into view when clicked on the map.
I have the feeling this just requires another step in my `change_selection()` function, but I will probably need to use JavaScript (e.g. something like `table().row().scrollTo(clicked_id)`) but don't know how to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we add this JavaScript code in the app:

```r
js <- '
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("scrollTo", function(id) {
    $("body").trigger("myCustomEvent", id);
  }); 
'
```

We will send the clicked id to JavaScript with this code, which triggers an event `myCustomEvent` with data the clicked id.

You add this code as follows:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(
    HTML(js)
  ),
  sidebarLayout(
    ......
```

Add `session` as the third argument of the `server` function, and use this code to send the clicked id to JavaScript:

```r
  change_selection <- function(clicked_id, clicked_county, from_table){
    if(!from_table) {
      session$sendCustomMessage("scrollTo", clicked_id)
    } else if (from_table) {  
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        removeShape("highlighted_county") %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc[nc$CNTY_ID==clicked_county,],
                    layerId = "highlighted_county",
                    weight=6,
                    opacity = 1,
                    color="white"
        )
    }
  }
```

Now we will listen to this event in the DT table. And we use the extension **Select** to programmatically select a row and the extension **Scroller** to scroll to a row:

```r
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(nc,
              callback = JS(callback),
              extensions = c("Select", "Scroller"),
              selection = "none",
              options = list(
                scrollX = TRUE,
                scrollY = "200px",
                scrollCollapse = TRUE,
                dom = "frtip",
                paging = TRUE,
                select = TRUE,
                scroller = TRUE
              )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
```

And here is the DT callback:

```r
callback <- '
  $("body").on("myCustomEvent", function(e, id) {
    table.row(id).select();
    table.row(id).scrollTo();
  })
'
```

It does not work in the RStudio browser but it works in an ordinary browser, even in Edge:

[image]

---

## Edit

The `scrollTo` method of the **Scroller** extension does not seem to work. So here is another way. The callback:

```r
callback <- '
  $("body").on("myCustomEvent", function(e, id) {
    table.row(id).select();
    table.row(id).nodes().to$().get(0).scrollIntoView();
  })
'
```

The DT table:

```r
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(nc,
              callback = JS(callback),
              extensions = "Select",
              selection = "none",
              options = list(
                scrollX = TRUE,
                scrollY = "200px",
                scrollCollapse = TRUE,
                dom = "frtip",
                paging = FALSE,
                select = TRUE
              )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
```

[image]